# How to bind data between components in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-components

I'm currently studying AngularJS and I have problems with data-binding.

I tried to make smth like data GRID. After "Edit" click data should appear in form. Then I could edit it inside form and, after "Save" click, data should update inside table.

[code in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mu7jfuOp9hVqbxn5O2fy?p=preview)

Component 1:

```
 //Click Edit
sort.openOrder = function(order) {
  sort.order = order;
  sort.addbtn = false;
  console.log(sort.order);

  let number = document.getElementById("test-form-Number");
  number.value = sort.order.number;
  let customer = document.getElementById("test-form-Customer");
  customer.value = sort.order.customer;
  let manager = document.getElementById("test-form-Manager");
  manager.value = sort.order.manager;
  let status = document.getElementById("test-form-Status");
  status.value = sort.order.status;
  let summ = document.getElementById(id = "test-form-Price");
  summ.value = sort.order.summ;

};
```

Component 2:

```
 // Click Add
sort.edit = function(order) {

  let index = order.id - 1;
  sort.orders[index].number = number.value;
  sort.orders[index].customer = customer.value;
  sort.orders[index].manager = manager.value;
  sort.orders[index].status = status.value;
  sort.orders[index].summ = summ.value;
  console.log(sort.orders[index].number);
};
```

I tried to read AngularJS documantation, but I don't understand how to transfer "order" data, when I click "Edit" inside 'tablica' component, into controller inside 'forma' component.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share data among different controller is to use a service.